# What do you call a person who likes to chat/connect to new people

Tags: single-word-requests

The one who likes/desires to know others(new persons)
such as on social sites etc.

Comment: They’re called extroverts.

Answer (score 1):

You could try, either

[Gregarious](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gregarious) - fond of the company of others

or

[Sociable](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sociable) - inclined to associate with or be in the company of others.

Comment: That'll work but what for a person who likes to connect with new people on social sites

Answer (score 0):

This person could be called a ***social butterfly***, which is an extroverted, outgoing person that finds it easy and enjoyable to meet new people and make friends. Similar to how a real butterfly flits about effortlessly from flower to flower, the social butterfly enjoys expanding upon and interacting with their large social network.

Comment: Social butterfly is Informally correct.